# Add event directive to svelte html expression?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I want to add a custom button through an html expression in svelte. 
Through the docs [here](https://svelte.dev/docs), I can do that using the *@html* tag.

```
{@html 
`
 <button>
   click me
 </button>
`
}
```

I would like to now add a directive event handler to the html string, namely a locally defined function that will be called when button is clicked. What I have tried so far:

```
{@html 
`
 <button
   on:click="${()=>doSomething()}">
   click me
 </button>
`
}
```

However, as I expected it didn't work. I was thinking there could be another way to this, but couldn't come up with one so far

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conceptually, using the `@html` directive is equivalent to doing `el.innerHTML = myHtmlString`.

Said otherwise, in the context of your HTML string, you're completely out of Svelte's realm (and completely in native browser's realm).

`on:click` is special Svelte syntax, the browser won't process that. So if you want events in you HTML string, you need to go back to raw HTML/JS. That is, use `onclick` instead.

Of course, the semantics of `onclick` are completely different from that of `on:click`. To `onclick`, you can only pass a string, that will be `eval`'d when the event happens (whereas with `on:click`, you pass a function *reference*, that will be called when the event happens).

To make this very clear, let's recall Svelte's syntax:

```html
<button on:click={doSomething}>Click me</button>
```

In contrast, in raw HTML, this would look like:

```html
{@html '<button onclick="doSomething()">Click click!</button>'}
```

See the important difference: with `onclick`, you need to *call* the `doSomething()` function, or nothing will happen on click.

Now, extra fun: this `doSomething` function needs to be available in scope... That is, you have to attach it to `window`:

```html
<script context="module">
  // note: using context=module to avoid adding this function to window
  //       multiple times
  window.doSomething = () => { ... }
</script>
{@html '<button onclick="doSomething()">Click click!</button>'}
```

This is ugly... You could do something like this instead, to avoid polluting the global scope:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    const doSomething = () => { ... }

    onMount(() => {
        const btn = document.querySelector('#grab-me')
        btn.addEventListener('click', doSomething)
    })
</script>

{@html '<button id="grab-me">Click click!</button>'}
```

Now we're polluting DOM ids... We could further avoid that by wrapping with an element that Svelte controls, to which we could grab a reference with `bind:this={el}`...

To sum it up, dynamic elements in `@html` strings are best avoided because you lose all the benefits of Svelte inside them. `@html` is best fitted for rendering static HTML content.

Why do you want to put your button in a string, instead of letting Svelte manage it?

If you really need going done this road, you might also be interested in [this dirty trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431023/1387519), that I absolutely don't recommend to use (I would never use it in my own code)... But this might give you further perspective on what you're trying to achieve.